# How can I ensure a live stream is stopped after the broadcast is done?

Tags: azure-media-services

Customers... Have to love them :)

I built out a web process that starts a live stream in Azure Media Services, but in testing I've seen a couple of times where the end user just closes the browser instead of clicking the end broadcast button I've so nicely set up for them.

The problem then is obvious, the stream keeps on running.  Multiply this a few times and I've now got numerous live streams broadcasting nothing but I'm incurring costs.

Is there anything in the configuration in the portal (or even in the stream configuration: client.LiveEvents.CreateAsync(....) ) that can stop these services even if they close off their browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways to approach this.

1. Your web application should prompt the user if they want to end the broadcast if they are closing the browser. This is a browser event that your web application can handle.
2. From the server side, you can monitor live events by subscribing to eventgrid events. 2 ways to do this as well. Please see the documentation on the [eventgrid event schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/media-services-event-schemas#live-event-types) to learn more about them.

You can either subscribe to the stream level "Microsoft.Media.LiveEventEncoderDisconnected" and monitor that no reconnection come in for a while to stop and delete your live event.

Or you can subscribe to the track level heartbeat events. If all tracks have incoming bitrate dropping to 0; or the last timestamp is no longer increasing, then you can also safely shut down the live event. The heartbeat events come in at every 20 seconds for every track so it could be a little bit verbose.

To learn more about how to subscribe to eventgrid events, you can read this documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/reacting-to-media-services-events)